# Xcode 5.1 compile against C++98, avoid C++11 features

Tags: c++, xcode, osx-mavericks

I'm currently working on a project that primarily uses C++98 as a coding standard for backwards compatibility. I'm working on OSX10.9 mavericks and have compiled all dependencies against `libc++`.
I would like to configure Xcode in such a way that it gives me a warning or doesn't compile when I use C++11 language features.

Compiling with the `-std=c++98` flag didn't show any errors/notifications concerning the use of C++11 features.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't enable the "Using C++11 extensions in earlier versions of C++"-warning. Now XCode will show me a compiler warning if I use C++11 features.

To check if I use library features from the new standard I still have to link `libstdc++`.

[image: Screenshot showing "Using C++11 extensions in earlier versions of C++" in XCode.]